# Update location before getting forecast

Tags: java, android, android-studio, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am making a weather app and my current issue is that the weather is updating based on the default values for the location rather than waiting for the method `getLocation()` to update the location. As soon as I refresh, everything works, but this is not what I'd prefer to happen in my app. Here is my `MainActivity.java`: Please excuse the mess. It's compiled from code snippet after code snippet and needs some re-organising.

```
package com.nrsmac.stormy.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nrsmac.stormy.R;
import com.nrsmac.stormy.weather.Current;
import com.nrsmac.stormy.weather.Day;
import com.nrsmac.stormy.weather.Forecast;
import com.nrsmac.stormy.weather.Hour;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import butterknife.OnClick;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String DAILY_FORECAST = "DAILY_FORECAST";
    public static final String HOURLY_FORECAST = "HOURLY_FORECAST";

    //9.927128 -84.082012 San José, Costa Rica
    private double mLatitude = 0;
    private double mLongitude = 0;

    public static String cityName = null;
    public static int backgroundColor;

    private Forecast mForecast;

    @InjectView(R.id.relativeLayout)
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    @InjectView(R.id.timeLabel)
    TextView mTimeLabel;
    @InjectView(R.id.temperatureLabel)
    TextView mTemperatureLabel;
    @InjectView(R.id.humidityValue)
    TextView mHumidityValue;
    @InjectView(R.id.precipValue)
    TextView mPrecipValue;
    @InjectView(R.id.summaryLabel)
    TextView mSummaryLabel;
    //@InjectView(R.id.iconImageView) ImageView mIconImageView;
    @InjectView(R.id.refreshImageView)
    ImageView mRefreshImageView;
    @InjectView(R.id.progressBar)
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    @InjectView(R.id.locationLabel)
    TextView mLocationLabel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        getLocation();

        mRefreshImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getForecast(mLatitude, mLongitude);
            }
        });

        getForecast(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        Log.d(TAG, "Main UI code is running!");
    }

    public void getLocation() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if (location != null){
                    double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                    double pLat = location.getLatitude();

                    mLongitude = pLong;
                    mLatitude = pLat;
                }


                String longitude = "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
                Log.v(TAG, longitude);
                String latitude = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude();
                Log.v(TAG, latitude);
            /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                            location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0)
                        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mLocationLabel.setText(cityName);


            }


            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };


//took this to line 123 out to test for gps always on bug, using only line 124 right now
        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        // try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        //try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}


        // if(gps_enabled) {
        // lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 100, ll);
        //if(network_enabled)
        // lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 100, ll);

        // }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 100, ll);
        // if update broke it, try un-commenting this line, comment out above line?
        //lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 10, ll);

    }





    private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
        String apiKey = "7a73984cc278e10ed332f1e5d6db96e9";

        String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

            toggleRefresh();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                    alertUserAboutError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            mForecast = parseForecastDetails(jsonData);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    updateDisplay();
                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught", e);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.network_unavailible_message),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void toggleRefresh() {
        getLocation();
        if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        getLocation();
        Current current = mForecast.getCurrent();
        mTemperatureLabel.setText(current.getTemperature() + " degrees");
        mTimeLabel.setText(current.getFormattedTime());
        mHumidityValue.setText(current.getHumidity() + "");
        mPrecipValue.setText(current.getPrecipChance() + "%");
        mSummaryLabel.setText(current.getSummary());

//        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(current.getIconId());
//        mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        backgroundColor = current.getBackgroundColor();
        mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

    }

    private Forecast parseForecastDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        Forecast forecast = new Forecast();

        forecast.setCurrent(getCurrentDetails(jsonData));
        forecast.setHourlyForecast(getHourlyForecast(jsonData));
        forecast.setDailyForecast(getDailyForecast(jsonData));

        return forecast;
    }

    private Day[] getDailyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        JSONObject daily = forecast.getJSONObject("daily");
        JSONArray data = daily.getJSONArray("data");

        Day[] days = new Day[data.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonDay = data.getJSONObject(i);
            Day day = new Day();

            day.setSummary(jsonDay.getString("summary"));
            day.setIcon(jsonDay.getString("icon"));
            day.setTemperatureMax(jsonDay.getDouble("temperatureMax"));
            day.setTime(jsonDay.getLong("time"));
            day.setTimezone(timezone);

            days[i] = day;
        }

        return days;
    }

    private Hour[] getHourlyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException{
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        JSONObject hourly = forecast.getJSONObject("hourly");
        JSONArray data = hourly.getJSONArray("data");

        Hour[] hours = new Hour[data.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonHour = data.getJSONObject(i);
            Hour hour = new Hour();
            hour.setSummary(jsonHour.getString("summary"));
            hour.setTemperature(jsonHour.getDouble("temperature"));
            hour.setIcon(jsonHour.getString("icon"));
            hour.setTime(jsonHour.getLong("time"));
            hour.setTimezone(timezone);

            hours[i] = hour;
        }
        return hours;
    }

    private Current getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        Log.i(TAG, "From JSON: " + timezone);

        JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");

        Current current = new Current();
        current.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
        current.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
        current.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
        current.setPrecipChance(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
        current.setSummary(currently.getString("summary"));
        current.setTemperature(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
        current.setTimeZone(timezone);

        Log.d(TAG, current.getFormattedTime());

        return current;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailible = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailible = true;
        }

        return isAvailible;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");

    }

    @OnClick (R.id.dailyButton)
    public void startDailyActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DailyForecastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DAILY_FORECAST, mForecast.getDailyForecast());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @OnClick (R.id.hourlyButton)
    public void startHourlyActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HourlyForecastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(HOURLY_FORECAST, mForecast.getHourlyForecast());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did kind of the same of yours, we are on the same boat:)

Remove `getForecast()` in `onCreate`. You need to update your current location by using google new `FusedLocationApi`,
because this avoiding `getLastKnowLocation` crash. How to use this please refer to [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android), and get the code [here](https://github.com/treehouse/android-location-example).

Then, you need to `handleNewLocation`(update the weather) in `onLocationChanged` method.

and the sample code:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        getForecast(mLatitude, mLongitude);
        getCityName();

    }
```

Remember, always check `mLongitude != 0 && mLatitude != 0` before updating the weather info.

If you still cannot figure out, please refer to my Github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/WeatherBo-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bojie/weatherBo/ui/MainActivity.java).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to getForecast in onCreate.  That will make it not try to immediately get the forecast based on the wrong location.  Only call getForecast after onLocationUpdates is called, so you have the right location.